# My files aren't read by my java program

Tags: java, dictionary

I have some Java code like this :

```
Map<Map<String,String>,String> map = new HashMap<>();
int i = 0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("properties.txt")))
{

        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                i++;
                String[] parts = sCurrentLine.split(",");
                System.out.println(parts[2]);
                Map<String,String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
                tempMap.put("issuing_bank",parts[1]);
                tempMap.put("card_switch",parts[2]);
                tempMap.put("card_Type",parts[3]);
                map.put(tempMap,parts[0]);
        }

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It looks strange that my `map` contains only first `12` elements that are stored from my text file. For debugging purpose I have used the variable `i` and print that out, which is printing the value of `22`, which is the exact count in my text file.

My text file looks like this:

```
447747,ICCI,Visa,Credit
421323,ICCI,Visa,Debit
421630,ICCI,Visa,Debit
455451,ICCI,Visa,Debit
469375,ICCI,Visa,Debit
523951,ICCI,MasterCard,Credit
5399,ICCI,MasterCard,Debit
517652,HDFC,MasterCard,Credit
558818,HDFC,MasterCard,Credit 
512622,SBI,MasterCard,Credit
526468,SBI,MasterCard,Credit
400975,Citi,Visa,Credit
402856,Citi,Visa,Credit
461726,Citi,Visa,Credit
552004,Citi,MasterCard,Debit
468805,Axis,Visa,Debit
418157,ICCI,Visa,Debit
524133,Citi,MasterCard,Credit
528945,HDFC,MasterCard,Credit
437748,SBI,MasterCard,Credit
524111,HDFC,MasterCard,Credit
431757,SBI,Visa,Credit
```

I'm very much confused, why only `12` elements are read into my `map`. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple: you have the wrong argument order in this line:

```
map.put(tempMap,parts[0]);
```

it should say

```
map.put(parts[0],tempMap);
```

You must change the type parameters of your variable declaration accordingly. Where you have

```
Map<Map<String,String>,String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

you must put

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Altogether, after these changes I believe you will have the structure you really want to have: a map from `parts[0]` to the map of the rest of the record fields.

I should add that your solution (in addition to your nick :) gives you away as a developer who primarily codes in a dynamic language like Groovy; this style is not a good match for Java's language features. In Java you'd be better off defining a specialized bean class:

```
public class CardHolder {
  public final String cardNumber, issuingBank, cardSwitch, cardType;

  public CardHolder(String[] record) {
    int i = 0;
    cardNumber = record[i++];
    issuingBank = record[i++];
    cardSwitch = record[i++];
    cardType = record[i++];
  }
}
```

First, this approach is nicer since your reading loop becomes simpler and more to the point:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  final CardHolder ch = new CardHolder(sCurrentLine.split(","));
  map.put(ch.cardNumber, ch);
}
```

Also this will allow you finer control over other aspects of your record; for example a nice custom `toString` and similar. Note also that this has hardly resulted in more code: it just got reorganized by the separation-of-concerns principle.

(A minor observation at the end: in Java the s-prefix to String variables is not customary because it is redundant in statically-typed languages; rest assured that you will never encounter a bug in Java due to an Integer occuring where a String was expected.)

Comment: Thanks! Haven't noticed that!

Answer (score 2):

You should change, how you have created your Map.. In place of your below declaration: -

```
Map<Map<String,String>,String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Rather than this, you should have a : -

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You should always **have an immutable type** as a key in your Map..

And **after this change**, you should change: -

```
map.put(tempMap,parts[0]);
```

to: -

```
map.put(parts[0], tempMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the arguments in

```
map.put(tempMap,parts[0]);
```

reversed. You are mapping tempMap to the number, where you probably want to be mapping the number to tempMap:

```
map.put(parts[0], tempMap);
```

Using

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Map as value since **HashMap equality is based on key value pairs it has.**.

```
map.put(parts[0],tempMap);
```

A simple program below will illustrate this fact

```
    Map<String, String> tempMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tempMap1.put("issuing_bank", "ICICI");
    tempMap1.put("card_switch", "Visa");
    tempMap1.put("card_Type", "Debit");

    Map<String, String> tempMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    tempMap2.put("issuing_bank", "ICICI");
    tempMap2.put("card_switch", "Visa");
    tempMap2.put("card_Type", "Debit");

    System.out.println(tempMap1.equals(tempMap2));//Prints true
```

Output:

```
true
```

So your declaration should like below. Remember you should always use immutable object as key in HashMap.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're using a map (the tempMap) as a key.
This is wrong.